# classifying problems with reducibility

Tags: terminology, computer-science, computability

How can we use a reduction to prove non membership of a class. Can we say if A is reducible to B they are in same class or if we can't reduce A to B. B is not same class as A.

Regards,

Comment: What reducibility relation are you talking about? Turing reducibility? Or something else? The answers will generally be the same, but the details may vary, and people can provide more helpful answers if you're more specific about the problem you're interested in.

Comment: Dear Benedict I meant Turing reducibility.Thank you so much for the answer

Comment: Great. Is there anything you're still missing, or does my answer cover everything you were thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

I'll talk about Turing reducibility. The answer translates to other reducibilities.

The answer to your first question is: It depends what you mean. Here's an example. Let $A = \emptyset$ and $B = \left\{ e \mid \Phi_e(n)\downarrow \right\}$ (the halting set). Clearly $A$ is Turing reducible to $B$, and $B$ is a recursively enumerable set. So $A$ is also r.e. and in this sense they are in the same class.

But while $A$ is also recursive, $B$ is not: its Turing degree is $\mathbf{0'}$ while the Turing degree of $A$ is $\mathbf{0}$. So showing that $A \leq_T B$ is not sufficient for $A$ and $B$ to have the same Turing degree; we would also need to have that $B \leq_T A$.

We can thus use the nonexistence of a reduction to show that a set does not have the same Turing degree as another. Since $B \not\leq_T A$, $A \not\in \mathbf{0'}$. (Note that we can be specific only because we know the degree of $B$: if we did not we'd just have that $A \not\in \mathrm{deg}(B)$.)

So in conclusion: $A \leq_T B$ does not imply they have the same degree. But $B \not\leq_T A$ does imply that they have different degrees. Hence, it depends what you mean by "in the same class".